# Calculate difference in Dates for each cell with next cell

Tags: mysql, sql, date, difference

I have a Data as follows:

```
Order_id       Created_on                       Comment
1           20-07-2015 18:35               Order Placed by User
1           20-07-2015 18:45               Order Reviewed by the Agent
1           20-07-2015 18:50               Order Dispatched
2           20-07-2015 18:36               Order Placed by User
```

And I am trying to find the difference between the

1. first and second Date
2. Second and third Date for each Order. How Do i Obtain this through a SQL query?

Comment: What would the desired output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is about horizontal relations - vertical relations do not exist. To a relational database they're just 2 rows, stored somewhere on a disk, and until you apply ordering to a result set the 'first and second' are just 2 randomly picked rows.

In specific cases it's possible to calculate the time difference within SQL, but rarely a good idea for performance reason, as it requires costly self-joins or subqueries. Just selecting the right data in the right order and then calculating the differences during postprocessing in C#/PHP/whatever is far more practical and faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.Order_id, t1.Created_on, TIMEDIFF(mi, t1.Created_on, COALESCE(MIN(t2.Created_on), t1.Created_on)) AS toNextTime
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.Order_id = t2.Order_id AND t1.Created_on < t2.Created_on
GROUP BY t1.Order_id, t1.Created_on
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this even though another answer has been accepted already - and I don't disagree with the accepted answer - but there is in fact a fairly neat way to do this with mySQL variables.

This query will give you the time between stages in minutes - it can't be expressed as a datetime as it's an interval between two dates:

```
SELECT
  Order_id,
  Created_on,
  Comment,
  if (@last_id = Order_id, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @last_date, Created_on), 0) as StageMins,
  @last_id := Order_id,
  @last_date := Created_on
FROM tblData
ORDER BY Order_id, Created_on;
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ffdd/10

Info on mySQL TIMESTAMPDIFF function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: You may not agree with my answer, but that will certainly change once you benchmark this query on a real-world dataset. This is going to be much, MUCH, slower than just doing the same while fetching in your data layer in the code.

Comment: I do agree with your answer, and I said so in my own. I would always do such an operation in my UI layer, but I found the question interesting, so I presented a possible way to do it in pure SQL.